# Display image left of href hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, href

So i've got wall of text with links, when hovering over the href it should display a image on the exact same line and always on the left of the full text, so not next to the link itself (meaning background image won't do the trick :( ). I've been tinkering around a bit, but without succes, so hoping you guys can help me out with this one :)

[image: Example Image]

As seen in the second screenshot, "kalender" and "menssana@home" are hrefs and need the same image next to the text. Wether it's javascript or css, any help is appreciated!

Html-example can be found here: http://www.menssanahealth.be/diensten/particulieren/

[image: Second Example Image]

Comment: if you send me a picture of your feather thing, i will make a http://jsfiddle.net for you :)

Answer (score 1):

I would nest a hidden image in the link and create a CSS rule on hover to show the image.

Basically this:

```
A IMG {
  display:none;
}
A:hover IMG {
  display:inline;
}
```

But here is a more fleshed out example using absolute positioning for the image so that it doesn't affect the layout of the link but instead shows up to the left of it.

http://jsfiddle.net/HLKQ3/

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS `:before` for this like so

```
.link:before{
   content:'';
   width:50px;
   height:20px;
   background:url('urlToYourFeatherThing.png') no-repeat top left;
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:-20px; // width of image
   display:none;
}

.link:hover .link:before{
   display:block;
}
```

Oh, and you may need your .link to be `position:relative;` so that the leaf is positioned absolutely to the parent.

This has not been tested, if you encounter any problems please let me know.

Good Luck.

@Connor

Answer (score 0):

- If you have an span with classname 'leaf' with in the a tag you can write code like below in jquery,

HTML should be like this,

```
<a href="http://www.menssanahealth.be/diensten/particulieren/sauna/" title="Sauna"><span class='leaf'>&nbsp;</span><strong>Sauna</strong></a>
```

Jquery should be like this,

```
$("#dienst-content a").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).find('span.leaf').show();
  },
  function () {
     $(this).find('span.leaf').hide();
  }
);
```

and the CSS,

```
span.leaf
{
   width:50px;
   height:20px;
   background:url('url-to-leaf-image.png') no-repeat top left;
display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Off topic, I have a couple of observations:

1. the page seems to contain a list of services so using a `<ul><li> ...` would seem more appropriate markup than `<p>-`
2. Some list items have links, others don't it would be more user
   friendly to differentiate a list item with a link from a list item
   without link -- e.g. use bold text, different color, add an arrow or underline etc

Back on topic:
Using a background image is totally feasible by using a combination of left padding and left negative margin. However if you really don't want to that direction then I would add an extra span within the `<a>`, and hide it unti the link is hovered.

Comment: The initial plan was to use <ul><li> but since it's wordpress, I can't really control how they make their text, so it has to be idiot proof ;)

markup-wise it's still being worked on as the site needed to be online before it was fully finished :)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution with jquery :)

You can see it in action [here](http://www.menssanahealth.be/diensten/particulieren/)

i've added the following script

```
<script>
   $('<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/bloemblaadje.png" class="bloemblaadje"/>').prependTo("#dienst-wrapper a");
</script>
```

And the css

```
#dienst-content{
    position:relative;
}

.bloemblaadje {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    margin-left:-60px;
    text-align: center;
}

#dienst-content a:hover .bloemblaadje{
    display: inline;
}
```

It might be heavy on a page with alot of links, but this seems the best solution for this design.

Thanks for the many suggestions!

Comment: Negative margins, using JS/jQuery when CSS will do, embedding server side code in script. These are bad design choices.

Comment: The jquery is to add those images as you described in your solution, as the person i'm making this website doesn't have the best knowledge it had to be fool proof for every link added to those pages.
About the negative margins, what's bad about that?

Comment: Negative margins? Nothing's wrong with using them. I would've used negative left... oh wait, I did in my answer.